# Flex Windows 8 - Software keyboard doesn't appear

Tags: apache-flex, windows-8

On our Flex app, on Windows 8 in Metro mode, when touching a TextInput, the software keyboard does not come up.
Strangely enough, if you set displayAsPassword="true", then the keyboard comes up.

How can I get the TextInput to work with software keyboards in Win8?

Comment: TextInput should automatically work.  What else are you doing that might affect it?

Comment: How are you creating / running a Metro app w/ Flex?  Running in the browser?  OR did they release AIR support and I missed it?

Comment: Running in the browser, with white-listing enabled by adding the domain to the registry as MS indicate in their docs

Comment: you should try tracing focusmanager.. it might not be selected..

Comment: https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3493295